# Java: Exporting data to SQLite database (*.db file)

Tags: java, database, sqlite, save, export

I have some data and I need to save it into new SQLite database (*.db file). Is there any way to do it without connecting to database?

Comment: You want to write directly to the file, without using a appropriate api/driver? Why?

Comment: The project already uses many large additional frameworks and I don't want to add lots of rubbish to it.
My needs are just to create 1 datebase with 1 table and fill it with some data.

Comment: you could use the sqlite shell CLI to build db files using generated SQL or CSV, but that would be even more of a dependency head ache.

Comment: I don't have your context, but my gut feeling is just to drive straight through the JDBC driver